# Click to increase height and decrease back to original height when click again with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

What can I do if I want to click on a button and then increase the height of the section by 300px and when I click on this button again, it decrease the height back to the initial height.

This is my code for the button

```
<div id="section">
   <button id="btn1">expand</button>
   <button id="btn2">expand2</button>
   <button id="btn3">expand3</button>
</div>
```

I have 3 buttons inside the div. Clicking on each button will increase the height of section by 300px and if clicking on the same button again, it will decrease the height to the initial height. What can I do with jQuery to make this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#section button").click(function(){
    if (typeof($(this).data('expanded')) === "undefined" || $(this).data('expanded') == "0") {
        $("#section").height($("#section").height()+300);
        $(this).data('expanded', "1");
    } else {
        $("#section").height($("#section").height()-300);     
        $(this).data('expanded', "0");
}
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sSGty/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('button').live('click', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('big')) {
        $(this).removeClass('big');
        $(this).height(originalHeight);
    } else {
        originalHeight = $(this).height();
        $(this).addClass('big');
        $(this).height(originalHeight+300);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").toggle(function(){
$("#section").height($("#section").height()+300);
},function(){
$("#section").height($("#section").height()-300);

});
```

reference [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: That will expand the size of the button, not the section.

Comment: This selector does not reference any of the buttons id's.

Comment: The link to toggle() is actually http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ , and it has been removed from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `btn` class to your buttons and use the click event for `.btn`. Check if the height is `300px` than remove the `height` else make the `section` height to `300px`

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var h = parseInt($('#section').css('height'), 10);
    if(h != 300)
    {
        $('#section').css('height', '300px');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#section').css('height', '');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="section">
   <button id="btn1" class="btn">expand</button>
   <button id="btn2" class="btn">expand2</button>
   <button id="btn3" class="btn">expand3</button>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VTWRG/1/)

Comment: Please include the html changes you have made as well in your answer.  Also, the asker has requested that each button increase by 300px independently, and decrease when the button has been pressed for a second time.